# can not run wp8 emulator

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I try to start wp8 emulator, but it always display generic error and failure.
I used coreinfo to show system info

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU         530  @ 2.93GHz
Intel64 Family 6 Model 37 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel
HTT         -   Hyperthreading enabled
HYPERVISOR  *   Hypervisor is present
VMX         -   Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization
SVM         -   Supports AMD hardware-assisted virtualization
EM64T       *   Supports 64-bit mode

SMX         -   Supports Intel trusted execution
SKINIT      -   Supports AMD SKINIT

NX          *   Supports no-execute page protection
SMEP        -   Supports Supervisor Mode Execution Prevention
SMAP        -   Supports Supervisor Mode Access Prevention
PAGE1GB     -   Supports 1 GB large pages
PAE         *   Supports > 32-bit physical addresses
PAT         *   Supports Page Attribute Table
PSE         *   Supports 4 MB pages
PSE36       *   Supports > 32-bit address 4 MB pages
PGE         *   Supports global bit in page tables
SS          *   Supports bus snooping for cache operations
VME         *   Supports Virtual-8086 mode
RDWRFSGSBASE    -   Supports direct GS/FS base access

FPU         *   Implements i387 floating point instructions
MMX         *   Supports MMX instruction set
MMXEXT      -   Implements AMD MMX extensions
3DNOW       -   Supports 3DNow! instructions
3DNOWEXT    -   Supports 3DNow! extension instructions
SSE         *   Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions
SSE2        *   Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 2
SSE3        *   Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 3
SSSE3       *   Supports Supplemental SIMD Extensions 3
SSE4.1      *   Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 4.1
SSE4.2      *   Supports Streaming SIMD Extensions 4.2

AES         -   Supports AES extensions
AVX         -   Supports AVX intruction extensions
FMA         -   Supports FMA extensions using YMM state
MSR         *   Implements RDMSR/WRMSR instructions
MTRR        *   Supports Memory Type Range Registers
XSAVE       -   Supports XSAVE/XRSTOR instructions
OSXSAVE     -   Supports XSETBV/XGETBV instructions
RDRAND      -   Supports RDRAND instruction
RDSEED      -   Supports RDSEED instruction

CMOV        *   Supports CMOVcc instruction
CLFSH       *   Supports CLFLUSH instruction
CX8         *   Supports compare and exchange 8-byte instructions
CX16        *   Supports CMPXCHG16B instruction
BMI1        -   Supports bit manipulation extensions 1
BMI2        -   Supports bit maniuplation extensions 2
ADX         -   Supports ADCX/ADOX instructions
DCA         -   Supports prefetch from memory-mapped device
F16C        -   Supports half-precision instruction
FXSR        *   Supports FXSAVE/FXSTOR instructions
FFXSR       -   Supports optimized FXSAVE/FSRSTOR instruction
MONITOR     -   Supports MONITOR and MWAIT instructions
MOVBE       -   Supports MOVBE instruction
ERMSB       -   Supports Enhanced REP MOVSB/STOSB
PCLULDQ     -   Supports PCLMULDQ instruction
POPCNT      *   Supports POPCNT instruction
SEP         *   Supports fast system call instructions
LAHF-SAHF   *   Supports LAHF/SAHF instructions in 64-bit mode
HLE         -   Supports Hardware Lock Elision instructions
RTM         -   Supports Restricted Transactional Memory instructions

DE          *   Supports I/O breakpoints including CR4.DE
DTES64      -   Can write history of 64-bit branch addresses
DS          *   Implements memory-resident debug buffer
DS-CPL      -   Supports Debug Store feature with CPL
PCID        -   Supports PCIDs and settable CR4.PCIDE
INVPCID     -   Supports INVPCID instruction
PDCM        -   Supports Performance Capabilities MSR
RDTSCP      *   Supports RDTSCP instruction
TSC         *   Supports RDTSC instruction
TSC-DEADLINE    -   Local APIC supports one-shot deadline timer
TSC-INVARIANT   *   TSC runs at constant rate
xTPR        -   Supports disabling task priority messages

EIST        -   Supports Enhanced Intel Speedstep
ACPI        -   Implements MSR for power management
TM          -   Implements thermal monitor circuitry
TM2         -   Implements Thermal Monitor 2 control
APIC        *   Implements software-accessible local APIC
x2APIC      *   Supports x2APIC

CNXT-ID     -   L1 data cache mode adaptive or BIOS

MCE         *   Supports Machine Check, INT18 and CR4.MCE
MCA         *   Implements Machine Check Architecture
PBE         -   Supports use of FERR#/PBE# pin

PSN         -   Implements 96-bit processor serial number

PREFETCHW   *   Supports PREFETCHW instruction

Logical to Physical Processor Map:
*  Physical Processor 0

Logical Processor to Socket Map:
*  Socket 0

Logical Processor to NUMA Node Map:
*  NUMA Node 0

Logical Processor to Cache Map:
*  Data Cache          0, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
*  Instruction Cache   0, Level 1,   32 KB, Assoc   4, LineSize  64
*  Unified Cache       0, Level 2,  256 KB, Assoc   8, LineSize  64
*  Unified Cache       1, Level 3,    4 MB, Assoc  16, LineSize  64

Logical Processor to Group Map:
*  Group 0
```

which hardware do I need to change?

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should execute the following to verify that the EPT - Supports Extended page tables (SLAT) is available.

c:> coreinfo -v

This flag will show only the virtualization features of your CPU.

For example, my output:

Coreinfo v3.2 - Dump information on system CPU and memory topology
Copyright (C) 2008-2012 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU    Q9650  @ 3.00GHz

Intel64 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel

> ```
> HYPERVISOR     -       Hypervisor is present
>
> VMX            *       Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization
>
> EPT            -       Supports Intel extended page tables (SLAT)
> ```

```
( asterisk means your CPU has it )
```

In this case, my machine does NOT support the ability to run the WP8 emulator because I do not have EPT (SLAT) capability.  You generally need an Intel i series processor.

Answer (score 0):

You may have another virtualization software like VMware installed, the output shows that a hypervisor is present.

Answer (score -1):

Your CPU (Intel64 Family 6 Model 37 Stepping 2) is a 5300 aka Clovertown aka **Core**-Based-Xeon CPU.

Win8 Hyper-V needs SLAT (Second Level Address Translation) or (in Intel terms) EPT  (Extended Page Table support,
which is only available on **Nehalem**-based Xeon (or newer) CPUs.

Comment: Yes, Intel CPU naming is a horrible mess.

Comment: Such a CPU would not have SSE4.2, for example.